# Firefox: html popup using relative path with unknown domain does not work

Tags: javascript, firefox

i want to use the javascript:open function to open a popup window from a image/icon.

Using a fully qualified domain works fine. The pages in question (both target and source) are generated dynamically by a servlet. Example:

```
<img src="../images/report_32.png" alt="test" onclick="javascript:open('http://localhost:80/my-servlet/reports/LOAN', 'LOAN', 'height=600,width=800,resizable=no')">
```

However, i would like to open the popup using relative links, with no knowledge of the specific homepage the servlet is deployed to. The following Example does **NOT** work in Firexfox (60.0.2), but works in Chrome (67.0.3396.87) and Edge (42.17134.1.0):

```
<img src="../images/report_32.png" alt="test" onclick="javascript:open('../reports/LOAN', 'LOAN', 'height=600,width=800,resizable=no')">
```

Does anybody know how i can get it to work with firefox, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
 onclick="javascript:open('../reports/LOAN', 'LOAN', 'height=600,width=800,resizable=no')"
```

to this:

```
 onclick="javascript:window.open('../reports/LOAN', 'LOAN', 'height=600,width=800,resizable=no')"
```